# [MoveIt] Executed motions are always slightly off from waypoints

Tags: ros, moveit, gazebo-ros-control

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I've been using MoveIt motion planning (OMPL) to simulate pick&place in the Gazebo environment. And I've noticed that the end-effector of the robot in the simulation is always off (~3cm) from given waypoints it needs to follow.

At the first time, I tried to set a specific tolerance value using **MoveGroupCommander.get_goal_position_tolerance**, however it did not make much difference. Then, I tried to reduce **eef_step** when using **compute_cartesian_path**. It still did not work as expected.

Right now, I'm suspecting that there is something wrong with my controller parameters that hinder the robot to reach to deisred waypoints. Are there any other factors that potentially cause this kind of behavior?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/411202/%5Bmoveit%5D-executed-motions-are-always-slightly-off-from-waypoints/) by [kidpaul](https://answers.ros.org/users/72845/kidpaul/) on ROS Answers with karma: 38 on 2023-01-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'll answer my own question.

Indeed, my controller PID gains were too off to follow the planned trajectory. After tuning those gains with trails and errors in the gazebo environment, errors became much more reasonable.

---

Originally posted by [kidpaul](https://answers.ros.org/users/72845/kidpaul/) with karma: 38 on 2023-01-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1